# Meteor Iron-Router stop running a route

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Before a user navigates away from my create post route I would like to ask the user for confirmation. If they say no then stop the new route from running. Currently everything is working expect the new route is always rendering; I can't seem to stop the router.

```
var isUnsavedCreatePost = function() {
    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result) {
        if (result == true) {
          this.next();
        } else {

        }
    });
}; 

Router.onStop(isUnsavedCreatePost, {only: ['createPost']});
```

Comment: try calling ```this.stop();``` in your else block and changing your onStop hook into an onBeforeAction hook

Comment: No tried that and also tried pause it's still goes to the new route

Comment: In your `else` block, you should try calling `this.render('some route');`.

Comment: The issue is that there is no way to stop iron router from rendering the new route. Once the onStop is fired it renders the new route.